# How to send a form on a distant API using symfony2 forms

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I made a bundle in my symfony2 project to handle all the webservices I use to save my files in the cloud (like amazon S3). Some of this webservices allow to send files directly on their Server without using mine with forms like that :

```
<form action="api.thecloud.com/specificId?redirectUrl=MyUrlToGetTheResponse" >
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The given redirectUrl param allow me to get informations from the upload and save its in my database.

My problem is that I want to make it transparent and customizable for the other bundles, like with a standart symfony form type. Is there a good way to do this ?

The solution I found is a bit complex and I think there is a cleaner way to do this :

I create a form type which specify the action url :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->add('file', 'file');
    $builder->add('otherPostUploadInformation', 'hidden');
    $builder->setAction( $this->Cloudservice->generateUploadUrl( 'my_redirect_url' ) ) ;
}
public function getName(){
    return '';
}
```

The action route is given in an other way (php or twig function) and saved in a session.

In my_redirect_url's action, I get and save the informations from the webservice and redirect to the action saved in session :

```
    public function myRedirectUrlAction() {

        $request = $this->getRequest() ;

        // Recreate a form with received information
        $rsrc = new CloudUploadRessource( $request->query->get( 'id' ), $request->query->get( 'url' ) );
        $form = $this->createForm(new CloudUploadType(), $rsrc );

        // transform it to array and add it to the request like if it has been posted
        $formArray = $this->transformFormArray( $form->createView() ) ;
        $request->request->add( $formArray);

        // redirect to the client action url with the request
        // So he can do $form->bind($request); $form->isValid(); ... 
        $clientActionRoute = $request->getSession()->get( 'clientActionRoute' ) ;
        return $this->forward($clientActionRoute, array('request' => $request ) );
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for me, it is kind a strangely to use such methods (uploading files directly to third party resource). Why don't you just use bundle like : https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpGaufretteBundle . You may configure as many adapters as you need. But in this case, you'll be able to test your entire application/project by just changing the addapters configuration for test/dev env.

Comment: I've seen this bundle. But with it, I have to upload the file in my server and after, upload it on the cloud. I try to upload it directly on the cloud to save bandwidth.

Comment: @Nikkidbz, - ok, in that case, it may be cleaner, to move all uplaod logic to JS(http://www.designedbyaturtle.co.uk/2013/direct-upload-to-s3-with-a-little-help-from-jquery/), to keep user on your site, without any redirects, and then handle it as a simple form with text

Comment: Yeah good idea ! But I maybe have to think about people who don't use javascript ?

Comment: Said nothing, that will pass by my server if he does't have js. So no problem. Thanks a lot